# multiindex for Excel output?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a .csv to which I'd like to add what are basically multi index column names, and write to Excel.  I'm just trying to determine if this is possible from the data/.csv standpoint, and then further if the output Excel can contain/retain the merged cell data.

I've been playing with both pandas.read_csv / to_csv and also csv.writer to add rows "above" the headers, but it's unclear if/how I can use multiindex to "merge" columns in the first two rows, which are not the header?  Thanks
[Input .csv and desired Excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbtbt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know how excel deals with the multi-index lateron, but the csv standard to deal with multi index is just repeating the column name.

This would be a csv-example for a multi-index:
a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,
1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,

I don't know if excel whould show index "a" as a merged cell.

But be careful. The table that you want to create has no "real" multi-index! Whereas "title,acres,sold" is a three staged index and leads to one column all other columns are supposed to have a three staged index as well. But "title,owner" already leads to a column with only two staged index.

Since your example does not have consistent rules it will be hard to figure this out with pandas and plain csv formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think what I was after is really feasible, and I have a tolerable workaround.